# AWS S3 - Assign limited permission to bucket & create IAM who can access that bucket only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm developing a mobile application & i want to upload/get/delete a file in AWS S3 bucket.

But I'm very concern about the security problem.

**S3 Bucket:** It should not be public and only authorize IAM user can access who have the permission to access my bucket.

So, need help to configure permission of my S3 bucket & create an IAM user.

Answer (score 0):

That is **not** how you authorize access for mobile applications. Yes, you can create IAM user, generate access key and secret access key, store those keys in the application code and configure right permissions for the IAM user. Then you don't even need to configure bucket policy. By default, bucket is private and only IAM users in your account with appropriate permissions are able to access it. If you allow IAM user to access specific S3 bucket then you would need to configure explicit deny on bucket policy to override it.

But the above approach is against every security good practice. What you really want to do is to create IAM role that allows access to the bucket and assume that role from within the application. You can set up Cognito + web federation (or some other web federation provider) for your users and ask STS service to generate short lived credentials using `sts:assumeRoleWithWebIdentity` command.

As for the IAM permissions, you will need to allow `s3:PutObject`, `s3:GetObject` and `s3:DeleteObject` so the policy can look something like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "<arn-of-your-bucket>"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can be even more granular and allow Cognito users to access only "their" folder inside of a bucket if you need to.

As for the role, you just need to attach the above policy to it and configure trust relationship between the role and web identity provider (as mentioned above, this can be Cognito or any OpenID provider).